# How can I express a SUM condition using SWITCH or nested IIF?

Tags: sql, ms-access, switch-statement, iif

I have a request with a SQL code which calculates working days of each of these activities: Interstaff, Mission, ``Congés` using a defined VBA Function.

When there are two activities on the same day, it counts 1 day for each activity, I want the Sum function to ignore this day, and go to the next one.

I would like to modify my SQL code to add this condition:

"When calculating mission, if there is a Congés within the same period, ignore this day (and give priority to only count it in congés)"

I read that there is a SWITCH or a nested IIF conditions, but I couldn't translate that within my actual code...

Please do consider that I am still a beginner, on his way to learning!

```
SELECT 
Z.Planning_Consultants.ID_Consultant,
Sum(IIf([Activité]="(2) Interstaff",WorkingDaysInDateRange([maxBegin],[minEnd])*Planning_Consultants.Time_Allocated,0)) AS NonBillable,
Sum(IIf([Activité]="(1) Mission",WorkingDaysInDateRange([maxBegin],[minEnd])*Planning_Consultants.Time_Allocated,0)) AS Billable,
Sum(IIf([Activité]="(3) Congés/Arrêt",WorkingDaysInDateRange([maxBegin],[minEnd])*Planning_Consultants.Time_Allocated,0)) AS Absent,
```

For example Mr A got a mission from 03/06/2019 to 07/06/2019. With a day off (congé) on 06/06/2019. I expect the output to be Mission 4 days and congé 1 day, in my case I will have mission 5 days, and congé 1 day,

Here's an example of a Dataset :

```
Activity    BegDate     EndDate     Time_Allocated
(1)Mission  01/01/2019  31/12/2019  100%
(3)congé    02/04/2019  05/04/2019  100%
```

For April for example, I would like to have 18 working days and 4 congé, instead of 22 working days and 4 congé

Comment: Please post some sample data.

Comment: Thanks, but what you should do is edit your question which will allow us test all of the columns in your sample query.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble formatting, i did my best though above

Comment: I would say that the second sum should be sum(mission days)-sum(conge days). The rest should fall out from that.

Comment: I did try that, but when there is no mission (0) it will still substract the congé and give me a negative number.
I only want it to substract it when there is indeed a mission

Comment: In that case the statement becomes a little more complex as you need to get the overlapping conge periods - presumably there could be multiple leave rows for a single project as well. Relatively easy to do with real sql, a bit more difficult in access though.

Comment: That's my current issue actually, whenever i have to input data, i have to do it manually from the start date to congé date, then put the congé line, then take back mission line again... For many people in the database that takes a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of query that should work for you. I've built this in sql server rather than access so you might have to make some mods, but it will give you the idea. It will give you the actual days for the activity, plus the total leave days that cover the activity. The rest I will leave up to you.

```
select t1.Activity, t1.Time_Allocated,
    WorkingDaysInDateRange(t1.BegDate, t1.EndDate) as days,
    sum(WorkingDaysInDateRange(
        case when t2.BegDate<T1.BegDate then T1.BegDate else t2.BegDate end,
        case when t2.EndDate>T1.EndDate then T1.EndDate else t2.EndDate end))
    as LeaveDays
from times t1
left join times t2 on t2.BegDate<=t1.Enddate and t2.EndDate>=t1.BegDate 
    and t2.Activity='(3)congé'
    and t1.Activity!='(3)congé'
group by t1.Activity, t1.Time_Allocated, t1.BegDate, t1.EndDate
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I will study the code and will work on it all day long tomorrow and keep you touched.